# why isDefaultPrevented check on a div in modal.js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

Hey guys was just going through the source of modal.js and came across the following lines of code.

```
$target.one('show.bs.modal', function (showEvent) {
  if (showEvent.isDefaultPrevented())  return // only register focus restorer if modal will actually get shown
  $target.one('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
    $this.is(':visible') && $this.trigger('focus')
  })
})
```

$target is actually nothing but the following :

```
<div aria-hidden="false" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" role="dialog" tabindex="-1" id="myModal" class="modal fade in" style="display: block;">
```

what i don't understand in the above code is why the check of isDefaultPrevented
is being performed on a `div` ??

I.E. the below line of code :

```
if (showEvent.isDefaultPrevented())  return
```

can somebody explain ?

my line of difficulty can be found on git too : [Line 331](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/js/modal.js#L331)

Thanks .

Answer (score 0):

I don't see where you think the `$target` DIV gets anything checked. Actually `isDefaultPrevented` is a standard [jquery function](http://api.jquery.com/event.isdefaultprevented/) which indicates whether user was trying to intercept the show event and thus influence default event handling. And this function is called for the event object, not `$target`

Answer (score 0):

`'show.bs.modal'` is an event name that is triggered on the div. This piece of code listens to that on event on that div.

Now, the point of the code you pasted:

If another piece of code already caught the event and called `preventDefault()` on the event object, then, when this piece of code is executed, it will know so using `isDefaultPrevented` and return without doing anything.

It's so that you can prevent the default behavior of that event, the same way you can prevent the default behavior of the `click` event, for instance.

Comment: i mean usually i see preventDefault being applied on `<a>` kind of  elements not `<div>` etc.

Comment: That does not mean you can't trigger events (and therefore prevent default event behavior) on other elements.